# 2D Physics library for multiplayer in c++

Tags: 2d, box2d, networking, interpolation, movement-prediction

Im trying to create a top down shooter with multiplayer functionality.
So far im using Box2D for my physics Simulation.

The last few days I played around with syncing movement between Clients and Server without box2d. I now feel like Box2d might be too complex for my rather simple needs(players are the only moving bodys, the Rest of the scene consists of static polygons) and after reading online it seems like Box2D isnt the best pick to sync physics over a network.

Especially when thinking about implementing client side prediction and entity interpolation where I have to manually correct values and interpolate between others I feel like box2d might be more of a Problem then a help.

As I noted my physics Simulation isnt too complex(just polygon-polygon intersection and raycasting) and so im currently thinking about implementing the physics myself so I have complete controll over it.

Maybe somebody here has already used box2d and networking or can point me to another library? Maybe im wrong and box2d is the best solution for networked 2d physics? :D

What about my idea of implementing the physics myself?